# stuck application at the same view even the class of that view is removed

Tags: android, maven

Im working with an **android** application ,even if I change the names of classes at **AndroidManifest.xml** the application still work and installing on the tablet but the weird thing that even I removed the launcher activity from the manifest I still got it when I run the app **the same xml view** !!!

As an indication Im using **Maven** too. 
I think the problem comes from Maven
this is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapps.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name="com.myapps.android.project.login.Connection"
             android:label="@string/app_name"  >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.myapps.android.project.login.Connection" > 
     </activity> 
 </application>  

</manifest>
```

I tried:

1. removing the R file
2. undeploying the application from the device with this comand:

   ```
   mvn android:undeploy -Pandroid-15 -Dandroid.device=usb
   ```
3. Uninstall the application manually from the device
4. removing maven android folder from .m2/repository

I still got the same activity while deploying the application to the device

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a little problem in your manifest: you are defining the same activity twice:

```
  <!-- First time definition of "com.myapps.android.project.login.Connection" -->
  <activity android:name="com.myapps.android.project.login.Connection"
         android:label="@string/app_name"  >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <!-- Second definition of "com.myapps.android.project.login.Connection" -->
     <activity android:name="com.myapps.android.project.login.Connection" >
```

you should remove the second one, it doesn't make sense to have a duplicated definition.

Did you change the `Connection.java` and/or `Connection.xml` and nothing hapened?